Differential op amp calculations
I have a project which involves passively reading the value of a 4-20ma circuit. I need to avoid interfering with the value of the loop while doing so. The compliance voltage is 24v so I should have plenty of headroom.
My plan at the moment is to use a non inverting Opamp (lm358 for example) setup as a differential amplifier.
I plan to use a high precisian 24.9r 0.01% 15ppm/C resistor in series with the loop.
I have a pair of potential dividers (100k, 100k) on each side of the sense resistor. I have a 150r resistor for feedback - which I think will give me a gain of about 7
The reason I have the potential dividers is because I don't want the opamp trying to pump up the whole current loop on the low side of the sense resistor.
My problem is - I'm not really sure this is the right way to go about this?
Is this a reasonable (and low cost) approach?
Opamp differential amplifier

We handle questions about writing computer programs. Electrical engineering is over there.
